# How to pass a python derived class to a C++ API call as a pointer?

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, swig

I am using SWIG to expose my C++ API in Python.
my C++ API expects a callback wrapper class pointer 'A'*,
I want my client (who is only using Python) to be able to inherit from that wrapper class 'A' and pass his implementation 'B' of that class.
(I went in that direction since I saw SWIG has some issues with passing callbacks to functions..).

So I defined class 'B' in Python and instantiated it, the issue is that if I try to pass the object as is to the function I get a type error (I think SWIG cannot convert the object to a shared pointer if it was defined in the Python code).
So how can I create a pointer to an object I defined in Python that inherits from a C++ class? is it even possible?
I thought about creating a pointer to the base class and telling it to point to the Python object but I'm not sure how to achieve that either...

I'm quite new to SWIG, is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible? am I missing a simpler more elegant solution maybe? thanks in advance.

```
//Callback.cpp

class DLL_EXPORT Callback
{
public:
    virtual void handle(std::shared_ptr<Data> data) {};
    virtual ~Callback() {}
};

class DLL_EXPORT Handler: public IHandler
{
public:
    Handler(std::shared_ptr<Callback> callback)
        : m_callback(callback)
    {}

    void handle(std::shared_ptr<Data> data) override
    {
        m_callback->handle(data);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr <Callback> m_callback;
};
```

```
//interface.i


%module(directors="1") example

%shared_ptr(Callback)
%feature("director") Callback;

%inline %{
    std::shared_ptr<Handler> createHandler(std::shared_ptr<Callback> callback)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Handler>(new Handler(callback));
    }
%}
```

```
//Client.py

class DummyCallback(example.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def handle(self, frameData):
        print("callback called")
        return

...

cb = DummyCallback()
handler = example.createHandler(cb) # <-- I get a type error here.
```

I tried creating a raw pointer but I couldn't figure out how to tell it to point to my create object,
or if it's even possible.
I read about typemaps and SWIG documentation in general but couldn't see a point of light.

Update 1:
I also tried adding this to the .cpp file

```
std::shared_ptr<Callback> makeShared()
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Callback>(this);
    }
```

but this causes a type error: "argument 1 of type 'Callback" *'

Comment: Please make a [mcve].